# Unable to sign into Outlook desktop app

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I am currently trying to fix an end user that is unable to login to the outlook desktop app. I made a change in ADSI edit and changed the primary proxy addresses SMTP:email@domain.com to the domain requested to be used. Then changed the domain in O365 admin to the updated domain. User was able to sign into mobile app and web app but no longer able to sign into the desktop app.
I see the following in O365 Admin
This occurred due to 'Keep me signed in' interrupt when the user was signing in.
,
Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '{resource}'.
&
Strong Authentication is required.

I have since reverted the changed and returned user to the original domain, cleared credential manager, enabled MFA, reinstalled O365, and user still cannot log into desktop app. What else can I check?

Comment: Did the user change the computer password?   Maybe you can log in, uninstall Office, restart and install / patch Office.

Comment: No, user did not change password.

Comment: Given all you have tried, I suggest (in order here) (a) Windows Repair Install and keep everything; (b) new Windows User Account; (c) rebuild the Windows System.

Comment: I have a test machine I use to replicate issues that I blew away, installed a fresh download of O365, tried signing the user in and got the same error.

Comment: Installed OS fresh.  ...  There must be some issue upstream with the email system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a while I have figured out the issue. The steps are as follows:
I had the user sign into their O365 account online.
Then click on the top right user account name and click on View account:

[image: See here]

From there a new tab opens, click on Update info in the Security info card:

[image: as shown here]

In this page I noticed their was an option for an App Password. I deleted that option and left it with only phone and Microsoft Authenticator and it worked. User was able to sign back in as normal authenticating via the app:

[image: as shown here]

To add. Adding the App Password sign in method generates an app password that you need to note down before closing the window. After noting down that app password users will have to use it to sign into any O365 accounts they are associated with.

Answer (score 0):

What is the detailed error message when you login the account in outlook client?

Could you see any error messages when you run [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365Ola/input) to test autodiscover?

Could you create a new profile in control panel?
[image][image]

Comment: There is no detailed message. When signing in an authentication window appears. As is it wanted to authenticate to our domain instead the authenticating to the Microsoft Auth app. We have tried creating a new profile the CP and when logging in Outlook does authenticate to the Auth app but soon after it just says there was an error with 3 options below. Can't recall what they are.